# android other activity click back key to listview ,the listview item can't click under the tab

Tags: android, listview, click, android-tabhost, back

I have a tabhost,

the tab A will connect A activity,

the A activity's layout have a Edittext, button and a listview.

the listview is customed from baseadapter.  the listview include a textview, not have button or image..,etc.

When I enter the program, the listview item is can click,

it will connect B subActivity.

But when I click back key, (go to back A activity)

the listview's item is not work, it have to drag up or  drag down,

the item will become click correct.

I have search some literary.

I had tried to add

```
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"

    or

    descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

in my listview , linearlayout or textview .

But the problem is exist.

how to solve the problem ? thank you very much.

My A layout is below:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/bgColor"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/drugText"
                    android:layout_width="224dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                    android:hint="@string/searchHint1"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="left" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/query"
                    style="@style/ButtonText"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_btn"
                    android:text="@string/search"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/drugList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

my listview item layout is below:

```
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/color_listview_border"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="60dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/drugNameTV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: just put your listview's click event in onResume method,it should work,let me know what result you got

Comment: I had put listview's click event in onResume();
 `@Override
 protected void onResume(){
  super.onResume();
  Log.e("log", "on resumed");
  drugLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
     View arg1, int arg2, long  arg3) {.......}});}`
But it's show error below.( the error is so long , i print photo here)
[link](http://134.208.3.130/~dickfala/android/err.png)
thank you very much.
I have use ActivityGroup to control back.
my activityGroup code is here.[link](http://134.208.3.130/~dickfala/android/ActivityGroup1.java)

Comment: I put my master code framework here [link](http://134.208.3.130/~dickfala/android/DrugQuery.java)
Thank you very much.

Comment: error is due to some null value,it gives you a null pointer exception so that just in onResume method some data are missing which are responsible to dispaly content on list view or any other elements of your xml file,just review it once i think you are so near to run your code perfectly,solve null pointer exception.

Comment: i am tried write `@Override protected void onResume(){ super.onResume(); Log.e("log", "on resumed"); });`When I click back from B subActivity to A subActivity. I am not see log "on resumed" show. @~@

Comment: I found cause this problem reason.
I change other layout, it's not have this problem.
causing this problem is edittext focus problem.
But I have't resolve now.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the listview state when you go to B subActivity.
After come back to A subActivity you need to restore the listview state.

Comment: When I come back, the A subActivity have data on the list, but it's can't click on the item. It's have to drag up or dag down, the item become click.

Comment: You clicking back key, A subActivity doesn't get focus automatically.Try to set focus on the activity or listview.

Comment: how can I get focus automatically, please?

Comment: You could overwrite onResume function of activity.

Comment: First thank you for responsed.
I write
    `@Override
 protected void onResume(){
  super.onResume();
  Log.e("log", "on resumed");}`
these code in the A subActivity.
But, I am not see log from B subActivity back.
If I add two line code below:
   `drugLV.setItemsCanFocus(true);
  drugLV.requestFocus(); `
It will show error.
  `FATAL EXCEPTION: main  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to   resume activity  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume   activity {xxx.xxx.ActivityGroup1}: java.lang.RuntimeException:   Unable to resume activity `

Answer (score 0):

just call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in onResume function